# C++ Function Overriding not working?

Tags: c++, overriding

I'm working on a game for an assignment and I've ran into an issue with function overriding in C++.

I have the following structure:

```
class GameEntity
{
public:
    bool GameEntity::TakeHit(int dmg);
};

class Enemy : public GameEntity
{
    bool Enemy::TakeHit(int dmg);
};
```

When from another class I create an instance of an Enemy, store it in a GameEntity vector, then call TakeHit() on it, it's calling the GameEntity version of it. I'm used to Java where this would call the other version, am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Other questions don't really cover this so I've created my own.

It's probably something pretty simple I'm guessing, so apologies for the trouble.

Comment: Note that "GameEntity::TakeHit" is invalid as standard C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare methods to be overridable via the `virtual` keyword.
EDIT: As pointed out in a comment, adding the classname qualifier inside the class definition is not valid C++ (but allowed by some extensions, such as in MSVC++=).

```
class GameEntity
{
public:
    virtual bool TakeHit(int dmg); // Can be overriden in subclasses
};

class Enemy : public GameEntity
{
    bool TakeHit(int dmg); // No need to write virtual again
};
```

Comment: it works in Java because all function are "virtual" by default. In C++ you need to be explicit

Comment: Putting in the virtual keyword was causing the build to fail earlier rejecting it, not sure what I did wrong but that's apparently exactly the issue I had trying it a second time. Thanks!

Comment: You should also consider adding the override specifier when you override the method.

Comment: It is written as in the OPs example, probably using MSVC. I can add a note about it in the answer for others?

Comment: @user1781290: You can be sure that someone who doesn't know about virtual member functions is not adding such qualification for good compiler-specific reason. It's used in Visual C++ for implementing interfaces. I guess part of the general COM support.

Comment: Using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, working with Direct X if any of that helps. It all functions perfectly

Comment: @David It might stop working if you switch to another compiler. With your current compiler this is ok and will work. I just edited the answer incase somebody else comes across the question and the answer does not work for them