# c++ print out array of objects with an overloaded function

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have an Animal class with a few animals that inherit from it. I'm overriding the talk() function. I need to create an array of objects then call the talk() function for each class. However, when when I run this, the only output im getting is "Animal can't talk". It's only printing out the output from the Animal class and not the output from the other classes.

also: if in the main I write `cowObj.talk();` the output is what I want "Moo!".

```
class Animal
{
    private:
    int Leg;

    public:

    Animal(){
        Leg = 4;
    }   
    void talk(){
        cout<< "\nAnimal can't talk!" << endl;
    }
};



class Cow: public Animal
{
    public:
    using Animal::talk;
    void talk(){
        cout<< "\nMoooo!" << endl;
    }
};



class Pig: public Animal
{
    public:
    using Animal::talk;
    void talk(){
        cout<< "\nGrunt!" << endl;
    }
};


class Snake: public Animal
{

};



int main()
{

    Animal arya[3];

    Animal animalObj;
    Cow cowObj;
    Pig pigObj;
    Snake snakeObj;


    arya[0] = animalObj;
    arya[1] = cowObj;
    arya[2] = pigObj;
    arya[3] = snakeObj;


    for(int x= 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        arya[x].talk();
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Function Overriding not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573414/c-function-overriding-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here not addressed in the [given answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53700290/10190237):
- You are assigning the `Cow`, `Pig` and `Snake` objects to an array of `Animal` objects. This can cause [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).
- Even if the `talk()` function is `virtual` in `Animal` class, it will not do what you expect it to do because you are not not calling it polymorphically. You will still be calling the `talk()` of Animal Object.

So what you need is an array (or better a `vector`) of pointers to `Animal` object.
And you can then assign the addresses of different animal objects to it.

```
Animal* arya[4];

Animal animalObj;
Cow cowObj;
Pig pigObj;
Snake snakeObj;


arya[0] = &animalObj;
arya[1] = &cowObj;
arya[2] = &pigObj;
arya[3] = &snakeObj;
```

Then you can call the `talk()` function like this which will result in the call being polymorphic:

```
for(int x= 0; x < 4; x++)
{
    arya[x]->talk();
}
```

See the demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c2724ad0ae40183).

Comment: I had to combine what you did here with the comment above about making the talk() function a virtual function to get this to work.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't **overloading** the `talk` function (i.e., providing different methods with different argument lists), but **overriding** it. In order to do allow it to be called polymorphically, you should declare it as `virtual`. E.g.:

```
virtual void talk() {
    cout<< "\nAnimal can't talk!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: This alone did not work. I had to also do what the below comment said. Create a array of pointers to Animal object. Thank you!